# How to keep the previous form parameter to current form, after validation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have 2 forms, form A + B

I choose an option from form A and passes great to form B.

After validation of the form B tho I loose selected option from the form A.

In the Controller of the form B I get the option from the form A like this

```
$option = $request->option;
```

and I pass it to the view like this:

```
return view('formB', ['option' => $option]);
```

Depending the option I show dynamic different title and different form.

So i have 2 questions:

1. How can i keep the option after validation
   and
2. Is this the right way to do the 2-step forms?

I hope that I was clear enough :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form, use `old()` helper. Eg:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="{{ old('name', $user->name) }}"/>
```

Comment: Hey Sreejith, thank for your answer. It's not form value parameter. The formB page does not keeps the option in page after validation of the form. I use the option parameters outside of the form.

Comment: in formB page the option is not in the form. I get option and i show a title which is from another query. how can i keep this? old it is not working in this case